# Phonegap navigation and session maintenance

Tags: android, session, cordova

I am trying to convert a website to a phonegap android application. The web server sets the session id on the client as a cookie. This session id has to be maintained for the complete session.

When I move from one page to another ( the second page is a local html file in the app), using href, or window.location, or navigator.app.loadUrl, it loads the second page in a browser, and the cookies get destroyed, so I can't make an valid ajax request from the second page.

I wouldn't prefer putting all the pages in a single html file ( like jquery mobile) . 
Given that I have seperate html files, how to navigate between them, such that the second page is loaded in the same webview,( so that the cookies are preserved) rather than in a browser. Do I have to create another activity for it ?

Is there any other way of navigation in phonegap, except those mentioned above ? Or is the only way of staying in the same webview is to dynamically load pages using ajax and replace the existing page with them ?

Another possibility is I can parse the session id from the response, store it in the local storage and append with every request. But this cookie is HTTP Read only, so I can't read it using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js is a great tool which has great  pagination routing feature, the hash will change but ur js objects will remain same because the page not being refresh, try it.

I think its better use localStorage than cookies, its easier and will go with your from page to another.

get notice, localStorage remains on device even user closed and reopen your app.

usage:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo","bar");
console.log(localStorage.getItem("foo")); //Output: bar
```

Comment: If I use localstorage, I will have to add the cookie value with every request that I send to the server. This seems a little tedious. Cookies automatically get attached to the requuest.

Comment: oh, i tought u need it for app internal use only. altought, if its defined values, u can set ajaxDefault settings if u use jQuery, which will send your defaults vars every request.